# Prove that $P_1\cap P_2$ is $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_{G}\left(P_1\right)\cap N_{G}\left(P_2\right)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $P_1, P_2$ be $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$, Show that $P_1\cap P_2$ is $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_{G}\left(P_1\right)\cap N_{G}\left(P_2\right)$.

Don't have any idea.. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously $P_1\cap P_2$ is a $p$-group so take an arbitrary Sylow p-subgroup $X$ of $N_G(P_1)\cap N_G(P_2)$ which contains $P_1\cap P_2$.

Then $X\leq N_G(P_1)$ so $X$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P_1)$, but this must be $P_1$ since $P_1\unlhd N_G(P_1)$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup. So $X\leq P_1$ and similarly $X\leq P_2$. This implies that $P_1\cap P_2 \leq X \leq P_1\cap P_2$.